# Match Parent alternative for width in Fxml (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, width, fxml

As in Android there is an option called `match-parent` that fits the component's width to its parent's width.
In javaFX ,
`fit to parent` option is there that fits the component's width and height both to parent's width and height.

What is the replacement for match parent in JavaFX that works for width and height individually and works dynamically means if we change width of parent then component's width should be changed accrodingly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any answer for my simple question..?

Comment: In JavaFX, it is the job of the layout (i.e. parent) to resize and reposition its children as necessary; different layouts do different things with their children. Check the the layouts in the [`javafx.scene.layout`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/package-summary.html) package to see if one fits your needs; a `VBox` might work for you. Note that layouts take into account a child's min/pref/max width and height. If needed, you can always create your own layout or see if a library is available.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Slaw ,if we set width and height statically using scene builder in javafx project and we made it run and changed the dimensions by dragging it,but the layouts and Panes are in their own dimensions not changing accrodingly,can we change them dynamically according to the parent.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] demonstrating what you're trying to do.